# Visibility of variables in MPI

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I'm still learning MPI and I have a question there.

Consider the following program. Say, I have declared few variables and I use them in few processes.

So if I define them before MPI_Init(where I have put a comment), are they visible to all the MPI processes?

If I use them in a another worker process, do I have to explicitly send them using MPI_Send or just use them directly?

If so how would it influence the performance and the data transferring of the program?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //define and initialize some variables

    //MPI init
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

    if(taskid==0){
        //master code
    }
    else{
        //worker code
    }
}
```

Really sorry if these are very basic questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: MPI processes are separate instances of (usually) the same executable. Each instance has a completely separate memory space and thus does not share any variables with other instances. Data can only be shared by explicitly sending and receiving it.

Comment: Use your favourite search engine to find definitions and explanations of *shared-memory* and *distributed-memory* parallel computing and of their differences and similarities.

Comment: I do know the the memory models, I wanted to know if there are copies of the same variable are initialized in all the processes when they are initialized BEFORE MPI_Init or have to explicitly send them

Comment: They are not initialized. You have go explicitly send them no matter when they're initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are initialized of course. To repeat, the same code executes in each process. If you had something like the following:

```
int main()
{
int x=5;
int y=6;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);

if(taskid = <whatever>) cout << x << endl;
return 1;
}
```

regardless of the value of , this code will print "5". I believe you really need to take High Performance Mark's advice though.